# Código para javascript para exibir div apenas em um tamanho tela x, Ex: pc

Tags: javascript

Estou com um código uma função javaScript, e na condição "IF" queria adicionar mais um parâmetro, do lado ScrollTop, Porque só quero que aconteça o slideDown se o usuário do meu site estiver em uma tela de computador. Deem uma olhada nele!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $(function(){
  var nav = $('.objeto');
  $(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 150) {
    //nav.fadeIn();
    $('#div').css("background","#06f2c9").slideDown(2000);
    //$("#div").animate({background-color:"#333"});
    
   } else {
    nav.fadeOut();
   }

  });
 });
});
```

```css
div#div{
  background-color:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:90px;
  top:0px;
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  
}
div#conteudo{
  background-color:f9f9f9;
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="conteudo">
    <div id="div" calss="objeto">Div para aparecer em tela de computador</div>
    Role para baixo.
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So adicionei o "window.innerWidth", ele pega o tamanho total da tela.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function(){
        var nav = $('.objeto');
        var window = window.innerWidth;

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (($(this).scrollTop() >= 150) && (window <= 767)) {
                //nav.fadeIn();
                $('#div').css("background","#06f2c9").slideDown(2000);
                //$("#div").animate({background-color:"#333"});

            } else {
                nav.fadeOut();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: vlw meu parceiro, de mais você

Answer (score 0):

Eu testei esse código e funcionou na identificação se estava acessando de um desktop ou não:

```
function eDesktop() {
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

if(eDesktop){
  alert('É Desktop!')
}
```

Esse pode fazer uma verificação do tamanho da largura da janela, porém como hoje em dia já existem tablets com resolução de um PC não seria o mais recomendado:

```
if (window.innerWidth >= 800){
  //acao para maior que 800 pixels
} else {
  //acao para menor que 800 pixels
}
```

Comment: Valeu mano só o que eu precisava era esse.
if (window.innerWidth >= 800){
  //acao para maior que 800 pixels
}

Comment: Que bom, então aceita a resposta conforme indica essa [imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)

Comment: ata nem sabia disso vlw mano, qualquer coisa te procuro de novo!